# What I can use to perform reliable screencasts / webinars for many people?

Tags: streaming, video-conferencing, screen-sharing

I need to stream my webcam video, or my screen contents, or both, to a group of 10-30 people. They don't need to stream their video or audio, they just need to have a possibility to send a question (via chat of audio) from time to time.

I have already tried:

- Skype. It's good for really small conferences, but anything bigger than 4-6 participants turns out to be unreliable, there are random disconnects or audio/video problems.
- Google Hangouts. They're mostly ok but there's a limit of 9 people.
- appear.in, based on WebRTC. Turns out to be unreliable too.